# Pandas : Joining two dataframes on a common column name and re-ordering the column order

Tags: python, pandas

First DataFrame : prac1 and second one : prac_dates
[image: DataFrame]

After writing the following code it gives the userwarning:

```
pracs = prac_dates.join(prac1,how='inner',on = "Month")
```

[image: Joined Dataframe]

What I wish to achieve is to
 1)Remove the  user warning and reorder the column sequence to ('Month','ShipName','ComoQty')and,
2) Rename the (shipname,01),(shipname,02)... column to (shipcount,01),(shipcount,02)...

Answer (score 1):

1. The user warning comes from the fact that one of your data-frame is multi-index. Either flatten the index or silence the warning;

```
import warnings

# ignore user warning
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)
```

2. Reordering columns in `pandas`;

```
>>> df.columns 
['wrong', 'order', 'columns']
>>> df = df['order', 'wrong', 'columns']
>>> df.columns
['order', 'wrong', 'columns']
```

3. Renaming columns;

```
>>> df.columns = ['new', 'column', 'names']
>>> df.columns
['new', 'column', 'names']
```

**Edit:**
To answer your question specifically, I gather that you just want to replace `shipname` with `shipcount`;

```
df.columns = [col.replace('shipname', 'shipcount') for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: in the renaming column part I want to rename multiple column having 'shipname' in the column name to other name

Comment: I've adapted my answer to your specifications.

Comment: well its not working throwing "SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized"

Comment: Updated answer.